# Magento 2export customer grid in excel format

Tags: magento2, export

How to export customer grid in excel format magento 2.

Comment: Do you want .Xls or .Xlsx extension file or CSV format is okay for you?? If CSV is okay then you can use @kishan solution

Comment: I need gird in .xlsx extension file.

Answer (score 0):

Open customers grid and click on top right **Export** menu. Then select **CSV** and click **Export** button.